# How to fix subprocess.call() error: WindowsError: [error 5] Access is denied?

Tags: python, command, subprocess, call, windowserror

## Hello!

I a trying to make a subprocess.call() to change the current drive to the C: But it gives me a WindowsError saying that the access is denied. This is the full Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1541, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Snake\snake.py", line 18, in open_file
    call("C:")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 168, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from subprocess import *
import shutil

root = Tk()
root.title("Snake converter")
def open_file():
    
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Snake files", "*.sim"),("Python Files", "*.py"),("All files", "*.*")))
    filenametmp = filename + ".tmp"
    print filename + " is being compiled. Please wait..."
    tf = open(filenametmp, "a")
    f = open(filename, "r")
    filecontents = f.read()
    tf.write("from simincmodule import *" + "\n")
    tf.write(filecontents)
    call("C:")
    call("cd C:\Snake\info\Scripts")
    f.close()
    tf.close()
    print "Done compiling " + filename + ". Find the file under /dist/[filename]/[filename].exe"
    
openbutton = Button(root, text = "Open", width = 10, command = open_file)
openbutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Any help that is given, even a suggestion, will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The call() method tries to run a process, but "C:" is not an executable. I suspect you can delete that line anyway since your next line does the change directory.

Comment: And your cd command must be broken down into an args list like:
`call(["cd", "C:\Snake\info\Scripts"])`. I don't know what you are trying to accomplish with the subprocess calls.

Comment: Trying to call `cd` with `subprocess.call` does not do what you think it does. The next time you call `subproces.call` it will not be run in the folder you `cd`'d to.